# Python: string.find('\n') always yields -1

Tags: python, string

I am trying to perform a `string.find('\n')`on a string with a couple of `'\n'` in there (I am looking for the end of a line). However, this always return -1 and does not find the `'\n'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the string you're looking in?

Comment: Please,have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question then.

Comment: The `string.find('\n')` should be able to locate the next line just fine. You should check the value of `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` method does not support regex. You need the `re` package:

```py
import re
m = re.search('\n', string)
```

More info can be found in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html).

Comment: This isn't a regex problem—`str.find` should work perfectly well with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the backslashes may be escaped, meaning your newline characters may actually be represented as two characters: a backslash and an 'n'.

To test, try using `string.find('\\n')` and check if that still returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok since you haven't provided the string, Let's assume `contents` as the string which has a couple of `\n`.

Let's replace all `\n` with some character like ™ using

```py
_contents = contents.replace('\n', '™')
```

Since you now want to get how many end of lines are there, You can use `_contents.find('™')`. This will return the no. of lines.